# Select an element in Selenium, Python, not by using XPath

Tags: python, css, selenium, web-scraping, selector

I was trying to scrape a website, and I need to select only the ul element inside the div with a class "Slider__SliderWrapper-sc-143uniy-0 jrPmnS", however, since there are many div tags with the same class, the only way I have to select just the ul I need is by looking at the href of the a tag, the one inside the h2.
I can't use xpath, because div tags always change position.

```
<div>
   <h2><a class="slider-components__SectionLink-sc-1r2bduf-3 jchpWs" href="rightOne">Right!</a></h2>
   <div class="Slider__SliderWrapper-sc-143uniy-0 jrPmnS">
      <ul class="Slider__List-sc-143uniy-1 MTYOL">
      the right ul
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <h2><a class="slider-components__SectionLink-sc-1r2bduf-3 jchpWs" href="wrongOne">Something else</a></h2>
   <div class="Slider__SliderWrapper-sc-143uniy-0 jrPmnS">
      <ul class="Slider__List-sc-143uniy-1 MTYOL">
      the wrong ul
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I thought about using `css` selector but I don't know how to, any help?

Comment: see these links, may be helpful [link1](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-to-handle-dynamic-changing-ids-in-xpath) [link2](https://www.jadeglobal.com/blog/ways-locate-dynamic-web-elements-selenium) & [link3](https://browsee.io/blog/strategies-to-handle-dynamic-web-elements-in-selenium/)

Comment: you CAN use xpath.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely CAN use xpath to access the href attribute AND it's contents:

```
//a[contains(@href,'rightOne')]
```

and for the ul:

```
//h2/a[contains(@href,'rightOne')]/../following-sibling::div/ul
```

Answer (score 0):

try `xpath`

```
//a[@href='rightOne']/../following-sibling::div/ul
```

**Explanation :**

You cannot use `css_selector` or any other `locator` since you are depending on `a` tag and you have to traverse upwards in DOM first, we are using `/..` for that, alternatively you can use `/parent::h2` and the next `following-sibling` using `/following-sibling::div` and then finally `ul` child

Comment: But in this way you are selecting the a tag, I need the ul, chid of a div, close to the h2 that contains that a tag.

Comment: @CalenBrow : Check out the updated answer !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a parent element with css selector, as it's not possible. Check here [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

In your case you would need to get the parent of `a[href=rightOne]` and get the `ul` of the following sibling.

With css you could use one of these locators:

```
div:nth-child(1) .Slider__SliderWrapper-sc-143uniy-0.jrPmnS>.Slider__List-sc-143uniy-1.MTYOL
```

Or

```
div:nth-child(1) .Slider__SliderWrapper-sc-143uniy-0.jrPmnS>ul
```

I would select any of XPaths proposed in other two answers if there are not restrictions on selectors.

But, if you are using such libraries as [BeautfulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), you will have to use css selectors, as it does not support XPath. So, use the ones I proposed.